# Dropddown header links to anchor

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, anchor

I want my dropdown menu header to both open the related menu and show directly the content of the first element of the submenu which is actually an anchor link in the page.
Here is the **HTML** code of the Dropdown Menu:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">     
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
          <li><a href="#submenu1" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">submenu1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#submenu2" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">submenu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the **HTML** code of the anchored link:

```
<div id="myNavbar" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="submenu1">
          <p>submenu1</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is the **JS** code I'm trying to use with no success. It works if I write a whole URL like "www.google.com" but not with "#submenu1".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').on('click', function () {
   window.location="#submenu1";
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you want `window.document.location.hash = "#submenu1";`

Comment: First of, it's `window.location.href`not `window.document.location`as you put it.
Second, lets see if I understand you correctly: You want to open up the new page AND go to the anchor inside that page? In that case, use: `window.location.href = new_page#anchor`

Comment: @TIMINeutron no, I want the dropdown menu to open regularly and the content of the first item to be shown in the same page. Like in this example [link](http://www.christopherandersonphoto.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the window.location.hash instead?

```
window.location.hash=anchorname;
```

*Edit*

You're using Twitter bootstrap right? The tabs won't be visible until the active class is added, and since you have a fade class too, I think you'll also need the 'in' class... Try this **JS**:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function () {
  // Remove any active classes from the tabs
  $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active in');
  // Set the specific #submenu1 to be active
  $('#submenu1').addClass('active in');
  // Scroll the window down to the tabs that are now visible
  window.location.href="#submenu1";
});
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve though, the links in the dropdown should do the displaying for you... but if you're just trying to force a specific tab to be open when you first click the nav dropdown, then this should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't work. The page gets the #anchorname in the address bar but the content is not shown.

Comment: I edited my answer - hope this helps, although I'm struggling to understand exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't redirect me to the required content. What I'm trying to achieve is exactly what is here [link](http://www.christopherandersonphoto.com/). If you click on a menu on the left, you will already see the content of the first item of the list, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

location.hash=anchorname

```
location.hash = "Submenu15";
var x = "The anchor " + location.hash;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/420rL0h2/

Comment: The problem is that the content is not shown. I want something like in this website [link](http://www.christopherandersonphoto.com/)